Why does my laptop screen blink or go black when plugging in the power adapter?
My laptop screen turns off when I connect or remove the power cable. (Charging cable.)
To be more specific, the screen will turn off and on again, it will flash to black for a short period of time and then turn on again.
Additionally, I have noticed that the screen colors appear to change when this happens. The screen colors are more vibrant when the power cable is disconnected and more muted when the power cable is connected.
I would assume this has something to do with automatically adjusting the screen for outdoor use - possibly.
The Operating System is Windows 11. The laptop is an ACER Swift Go 16.

There are two things to check:

HDR settings
Automatic HDR settings change when optimizing for battery life

To find these settings, open the Windows 11 Settings App, and search HDR
Select HDR settings
Turn OFF "Use HDR"
You may also want to change the option Battery Options: When viewing HDR content on battery power: Change to Optimize for image quality
I have owned this laptop for over a year and it has taken me ages to figure out why the screen was flashing to black whenever I connected or removed the charger cable. I thought something was broken, as if there was an electrical or firmware fault or something.
Turns out I was wrong and it's a HDR setting.
